# Error: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio, rows, export-to-csv

I want to read a xlsx-file and write each row separately, as csv-files. My idea was to first select one row and save this one, then take the names that are are specified in one column apart and loop through this. How my code looks like:

```
## read xlsx-file

dataset_allsheets <- read_xlsx("U:/my_path/model/R/file.xlsx", 
                                       sheet = "TOTAL", 
                                       range = "B3:FJ398")

## take only the column where name is specified

subset_countrynames <- dataset_allsheets[,1]


## create loop
for(i in subset_countrynames){

    country <- i

## connect data from the specific country and save  as csv

one_country <- as.data.frame(dataset_allsheets[dataset_allsheets$Countryname==country,])

write.csv2(one_country, file = paste("08052018",country,".csv"))

}
```

When I run this it returns the following error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

When I give 'country' manually a name that exists in the dataframe it works and writes the csv perfectly. I also deleted all the NAs. So there seems to be a problem with the loop. Anyone that has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The variable "country" in the paste of write.csv2 is not valid, probably it has more than one value. You may try to debug it by verifying if "subset_countrynames" actually is an array of country names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked and 'subset_countrynames' is an array of names and are string variables. So I would expect that it wouldn't give a problem in the paste of write.csv2..

Comment: After running the error, what is the output when you run "str(country)" in the console?

Comment: If I run str(country) the output is: chr [1:395] "country1" "country2" "country3". . . It gives the names of all the countries.

Comment: I would also suggest to change the paste function to paste0 (a paste without spaces between arguments).

Comment: Your country variable shoud be only one country, i. e. chr "one_country_name". Probably "subset_countrynames" is an array of arrays or a list of arrays. You may try str(subset_countrynames) to verify it.

Comment: Thanks! Will look for that to solve. I'll post something if it works out or if I'll still face problems.

Comment: Ok, if you show me the output of str(subset_countrynames) I can help with the sintax if needed :)